# How do I force a particular version of CSS in Visual Studio?

Tags: html, visual-studio-2010, css

I have a web project targeting .NET Framework 2 under Visual Studio 2010.

The Master Page is defined as:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
```

The CSS file is named Master.css.

Attributes such as `overflow-y: scroll;` appear highlighted in warnings as unknown property names. The validation rules being applied are CSS 2.1.

Is there a way to declare which version of CSS my code should be validated against? Also, when this code eventually runs on a browser, is there a way to force rendering using a specific CSS version?

Please bear with me as I am not aware of the relationship (if any) between the doctype of the HTML page and CSS validation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CSS doesn't "do" versions - that is, you can't identify your CSS as a certain version.
Of course, there are different versions, but that is more for keeping track of which browsers support how much of the standard than for tagging what kind of CSS authors use.

That said, Visual Studio has a Stylesheet toolbar, where you can choose the version to check against.

Edit: oh, and no, the HTML Doctype doesn't have anything to do with the CSS.

Answer (score 2):

Visual studio is warning you that is all. What VS is saying is that with the current version selected (2.1) it doesn't believe that style to be valid given the currently selected intellisense CSS schema.

If you want to remove this validation warning , if you are using VS 2010 you can update to service pack 1 and this comes with CSS 3 validation.

**EDIT**
Try this vs extension for css3. Bonus of css3 intellisense !
http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/7211bcac-091b-4a32-be2d-e797be0db210/view/Discussions

Comment: Well, I have Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate SP1. The Style Sheet toolbar, however only has CSS 1.0, 2.0 and 2.1. Any idea on how to add CSS 3.0?